# Select the most recent date in a LINQ query with an inner join

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a LINQ query that queries two tables, and returns records successfully. I want it to only return the most recent record, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. It returns all of the records without an error.

My query is:

```
  var viewModel = from area in db.area
                  join sample in db.sample on area.location_id equals sample.location_id
                  from s in db.sample.OrderByDescending(s => s.sample_date).Take(1)

                  select new AreaViewModel { h_area = area, s_sample = sample };

                  return View(viewModel);
```

Totally stuck, help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Take()` method at wrong place, you have to write something like:

```
var viewModel = (from area in db.area
                 join sample in db.sample on area.location_id equals sample.location_id
                 from s in db.sample
                 select new AreaViewModel 
                       { 
                         h_area = area, 
                         s_sample = sample 
                       }).OrderByDescending(s => s.s_sample.sample_date)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

if you want to return collection, then you can use `Take(1)`there instead of `FirstOrDefault()`, as it will not return collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is this:

```
var area= (from area in db.area
           join sample in db.sample on area.location_id equals sample.location_id
           orderby sample.sample_date descending
           select new AreaViewModel { h_area = area, s_sample = sample }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Calling [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549141(v=vs.110).aspx) method you will get the most recent record  due to it adds TOP(1) to the SQL query that is generated by your Linq query.